# ZooKeeper node watch called mutiple times

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I've stumbled upon a scenario when a node watch gets called multiple times, despite the documentation stating whose are one time invocations:

1. Set up a watch on a node.
2. Make the session expire.
3. The watch is called with ZOO_SESSION_EVENT and ZOO_CONNECTING_STATE.
4. After this the watch is called again with ZOO_SESSION_EVENT and ZOO_EXPIRED_SESSION_STATE.

Is this the expected behavior? Did I miss something from the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found this in the docs:

> When you disconnect from a server (for example, when the server
>   fails), you will not get any watches until the connection is
>   reestablished. For this reason session events are sent to all
>   outstanding watch handlers. Use session events to go into a safe mode:
>   you will not be receiving events while disconnected, so your process
>   should act conservatively in that mode.